# Declaring property in a class that has the type of another one in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I'm new to C++, but I have previous programming experience in PHP and C# (OOP).
What I have is: two classes one of which has a private property with the type of the other class.
Source:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(int n)
        {

        }
};

class Bar
{
    private:
        Foo foo;

    public:
        Bar()
        {
            this->foo = Foo(10);
        }
};

Bar bars[123];
```

What I'm trying to do is declare a property of `Foo` with a constructor in `Bar`. Unfortunately, the way I did it doesn't work. It gives a series of errors e.g.

> no matching function for call to 'Foo::Foo()'

How do I get it working?
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize `Foo` properly in a [member initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), like so:

```
class Bar
{
    private:
        Foo foo;

    public:
        Bar() :
            foo(10)
        {}
};
```

Otherwise, what happens is that the compiler first tries to initialize `this->foo` with a default constructor before getting into the body of your constructor. Since `Foo` doesn't have one, it fails to compile.